# filter list to first 2 case classes per parameter value in scala dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark-dataset

I have a spark dataset like this:

```
+--------+--------------------+
|     uid|     recommendations|
+--------+--------------------+
|41344966|[[2133, red]...|
|41345063|[[11353, red...|
|41346177|[[2996, yellow]...|
|41349171|[[8477, green]...|

res98: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[userItems] = [uid: int, recommendations: array<struct<iid:int,color:string>>]
```

I want to filter each recommendations array, to contain the first two of each color. Pseudo example:

`[(13,'red'), (4,'green'), (8,'red'), (2,'red'), (10, 'yellow')]`

would become

`[(13,'red'), (4,'green'), (8,'red'), (10, 'yellow')]`

How can I efficiently do this in scala with datasets? Is there an elegant solution using something like `reduceGroups`?

What I have so far:

```
case class itemData (iid: Int, color: String)

val filterList = (recs: Array[itemData], filterAttribute, maxCount) => {
  // filter the list somehow... using the max count and attribute
  })

dataset.map(d => filterList(d.recommendations, "color", 2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explode the recommendations, then create a row number partition by uid and color and finally filter out the row numbers greater than 2. The code should look like below. I hope it helps.

```
//Creating Test Data
val df = Seq((13,"red"), (4,"green"), (8,"red"), (2,"red"), (10, "yellow")).toDF("iid", "color")
  .withColumn("uid", lit(41344966))
  .groupBy("uid").agg(collect_list(struct("iid", "color")).as("recommendations"))

df.show(false)
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
|uid     |recommendations                                     |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
|41344966|[[13,red], [4,green], [8,red], [2,red], [10,yellow]]|
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+

val filterDF = df.withColumn("rec", explode(col("recommendations")))
    .withColumn("iid", col("rec.iid"))
    .withColumn("color", col("rec.color"))
    .drop("recommendations", "rec")
    .withColumn("rownum",
      row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("uid", "color").orderBy(col("iid").desc)))
    .filter(col("rownum") <= 2)
    .groupBy("uid").agg(collect_list(struct("iid", "color")).as("recommendations"))

filterDF.show(false)
+--------+-------------------------------------------+
|uid     |recommendations                            |
+--------+-------------------------------------------+
|41344966|[[4,green], [13,red], [8,red], [10,yellow]]|
+--------+-------------------------------------------+
```